# A special character is appended before §

Tags: java, linux, servlets, jboss

I have a client application which is sending a request to a server. Server is fetching a field from a database and sending a `java.lang.String` response back to the client. Server is running on JBoss v5.0. The unusual thing is that, when server is running on Windows machine, the response received by the client is normal but when it is running on Linux there is some problem in the encoding.

This is the data in the database: `"INET§IMPNG\n"`

Response is correctly received when server running on Windows.

A special character is appended before `§` when the server is running on Linux. Is there any special thing i need to do at the server side. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The response received is : `INETÂ§IMPNG`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is almost certainly a character encoding issue. To avoid mismatches between client and server, always specify a specific encoding and avoid the default encoding. (So, for instance, instead of `"xyz".getBytes()`, use `"xyz".getBytes("UTF-8")`

Comment: do i also need to set the response content type?

Comment: @HashimR - It certainly can't hurt. The receiver should also be written to examine the content type for a charset specification and honor it. (If both ends are under your control, you can cut some corners here without apparent harm. But I would advise against that because it just creates a buried land mine that will blow up in the future when one end is "upgraded".)

Comment: So what i get from your above comment is that content type should not be set as it would effect scalability of the program. Only using `"xyz".getBytes("UTF-8")` is enough for now. Did i get it right? :)

Comment: @HashimR - Wrong take-away. _Not_ using a content-type header (and, more specifially, the charset attribute) will adversely affect scalability. Your server code should use an explicit encoding when it is generating the response and it should generate a content-type header that specifies what charset it used ("charset" in HTTP terminology is the same as "encoding" in Java terminology). The receiver should examine the content-type header for a charset attribute and use it if present. Using UTF-8 throughout is probably the most robust choice.

Comment: I tried your solution but its still displaying that special character. And the funny thing is, it is now also displaying that character when server is running on Windows. :(

Comment: @HashimR - Actually, I think that's progress. I think the problem is now isolated to the client side. How are you reading the response?

Comment: `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (urlc.getInputStream ()));`

Comment: That's the final step. Change it to `new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")`. Note that eventually you should replace `"UTF-8"` with the value of the `charset` attribute of the content-type header (if one is present) and only use "UTF-8" as a fall-back.

Comment: @TedHopp: you're not completely correct. In HTTP and other protocols, there is agreement on the transfer encoding chosen (see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.2). If you blindly send UTF-8, you may well have sent data using the wrong encoding because the client specified `Accept-Encoding: iso-8859-1;q=1 unicode-1-1;q=0` and the Server therefore chose encoding `iso-8859-1`.

Comment: @parasietje - Yes, for the most robust design the client should send an accept-charset header that includes either "*" or "UTF-8" in order to receive UTF-8. Since OP controls both sides of this connection, sending UTF-8 isn't exactly sending it blindly.

Comment: I agree completely :) I posted the comment before reading the thread all the way through.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are seeing here is because the Linux server defaults to sending the String as UTF-8. In UTF-8, regular ASCII characters are encoded as a single byte. The § character is encoded as two bytes. If you decode this using CP-1252, you will see Â§ because the two bytes are interpreted as two separate characters.

The windows server will use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252, which can encode the § as a single byte.

If you are using your own protocol, you should specify which character encoding to use over the wire. I suggest you default to UTF-8 (internet standard). When sending the string, you should use `"xyz".getBytes("UTF-8")`. If you receive the string, you should use `new String(bytes, "UTF-8")`.

If you are using HTTP, your client should honor the headers in section 14 of the HTTP spec. I propose you use an implemented HTTP client like Apache Commons HTTPClient or the built-in J2SE one. On the server-side, you should use the `response.getWriter()` method in the Servlet to get a writer which will automatically use the agreed encoding. Please note you cannot just output bytes, since the server and client may have agreed upon another transfer-encoding for the HTTP stream!